# How to select the students with the highest marks for each dicipline

Tags: sql, sas

suppose i have dataset like below.here i need to get output which student got high marks in each subject and student name should be there in output ?

```
input student$ phy math chem eng;
datalines;
raju 89 56 37 99
raki 80 90 76 45
rani 56 65 88 43
ramya 67 98 70 67
;
```

Use any method (datasep, proc sql or other procedure)

Comment: Please edit your question to define 'high marks', and indicate the output you would like.  Also please show what code you have tried.

Comment: Per SO rules for questions, you need to show what you've attempted and what isn't working. As posted, this question does not meet the rules for a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the fact that temporary arrays are automatically retained:

```
data chapions (keep=student high_score);
    set scores end=last;
    array score {} phy math chem eng;
    array high {4} _temporary_ ;
    array champ {4} $ _temporary_ ;
    if _N_ eq 1 then do dicipline = 1 to 4;
        high(dicipline) = score(dicipline);
        champ(dicipline) = student;
    end;
    else  do dicipline = 1 to 4;
        if high(dicipline) lt score(dicipline) then do;
            high(dicipline) = score(dicipline);
            champ(dicipline) = student;
        end;
    end;
    if last then do dicipline = 1 to 4;
        high_score = high(dicipline);
        student = champ(dicipline) ;
        output;
    end;
run;
```

*Untested draft, to be improved when the question is improved with a proper description of the desired output*